# asp.net ajax container takes eons to load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I'm using 2 asp.net ajax tab container for a mostly intranet used asp.net application in a single screen.

Thing is, eventually it might have to be accesed through internet and it's taking 15-17 seconds to load and 35-40 seconds after a Response.Redirect() when it's accesed through internet. In intranet it works alright.

I'm using asp.net 4.0 with the tabcontainer from the AjaxControlToolkit version 3.0.30930.0 in IIS 6.0 and Windows Server 2003 on a Dual Core server. Is there anything I have to set/do for that webcontrol to work properly when the application is used from internet? Is there anything in particular which could screw that webcontrol performance?

Comment: First, check the size of the rendered page. If it is normal, use profiler to see which methods are slow to execute and optimize them.

Comment: @Genady OP said it works well in intranet, so its surely a page (or related resources) size issue

Answer (score 1):

Try using a tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to look at what is being sent to and from the server. It sounds like your page size might be really big which works okay over a fast intranet connection but is slow over the internet.

Enabling [compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692872(VS.90).aspx) on the server will help if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working fine internally and worse on the outside (internet), then it seems more likely that your issue is network related either on your ISP's side or somewhere in your path to the net...

Answer (score 0):

**what could be screwing the performance:**

- A large ViewState.
- A large amount of page content.
- A large amount of separate requests being triggered from said tab or with a large size on these (which could be implicitly with images or any other external resources being)
- An awful connection on either side / while it may be, not likely the real problem

Find out what you are receiving from the server / fiddler.

Check not only the size of the page, but also how many other requests are activated / for images, etc. Also check the size of the related requests.

Without checking the above is hard to tell the best way to proceed.

I've seen some awfully large viewstate / one of such cases was even caused by a third party control used in the page.

Answer (score 0):

if you place many tabs with large contents each one it'll likely turn slow and it wont be an ajax tabcontainer control problem